# How to prepare a statement from the CLI interpreter?

Tags: sqlite, prepared-statement, command-line-interface

How does one prepare a statement from the SQLite CLI? I have found the page [Compiling An SQL Statement](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) but it is geared more towards the ODBC interface, not the CLI interpreter. I'm hopinpg for something akin to the following:

```
sqlite> pq = prepare(SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=?)
sqlite> run(pq, 'jeffatwood')
0 | jeffatwood | hunter2 | admin
sqlite>
```

Does the SQLite CLI have any such functionality? Note that I am not referring to the Bash CLI but rather [SQLite's CLI interpreter](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) or the excellent [LiteCLI](https://www.pgcli.com/launching-litecli.html) alternative.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps [SQL Parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#sql_parameters) using named parameters would do the trick

```
sqlite> .param set :user 'jeffatwood'
sqlite> select * from Users where username = :user
```

should return the desired row.

Comment: Thank you Dino. Though often confused, Parameterized queries are not Prepared Statements. Upvoting anyway because I'm sure that other people coming here may have similar confusion.

Comment: That's kind of you, thanks. I guess this confused me "_debugging a Python script and I seems to find a difference in the results that a query returns when run as a prepared statement with bound parameters vs. putting the variables right in the SQL._". There is no explicit `prepare` method in python that I am aware of, like there is in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

CLI was not designed for such. For this you must use an SQLite API on an available programming language.

You may also write a batch/shell file to handle CLI call.

E.g., in Windows a file named `User.bat` like following:

```
@SQLITE3.EXE some.db "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='%~1'"
```

May be called like this:

```
User "jeffatwood"
```

will perform desired result.

EDIT:

About prepared/compiled statements: with those you can bind parameters, fetch queries row by row and repeat same command in a faster manner.

sqlite3 CLI tool wouldn't take any advantage on those:

- all parameters must be typed in SQL statement, making binding useless;
- all query rows are returned at once, no need to fetch row by row;
- repeated commands must be retyped - small speed improvement would result in using precompiled statements.

Comment: Thanks. Note that your batch file example is wrong, it does _not_ use a prepared statement.

Comment: "CLI was not designed for such" - It wouldn't even make sense in this context, as batch is calling a new instance of SQLite - a new connection, ... - every time is called. You can get no advantage from prepared statements here. Neither would you with CLI.

Comment: I mean the `sqlite3` CLI, not the Bash CLI. I will clarify that in the question. Thanks.

Comment: I understood that. Note SQLite3 CLI is supposed to use typed SQL. Prepared statements is more like a application concept.

Comment: sqlite3 CLI is tool. You're not supposed to write applications over it. You may call sqlite3 from a application (as I suggested with batch). If you are writing an application, you must be using some sort of language and SQLite is ported in many. In your application context, prepared statements would make sense.

Comment: I use the CLI tool to test the queries that will be run in my apps. At the moment I am debugging a Python script and I seems to find a difference in the results that a query returns when run as a prepared statement with bound parameters vs. putting the variables right in the SQL. That is why I need to run prepared statements from the CLI. In the interm I have written a simplified Python script to help me debug.

Comment: By the way, please remove the .bat suggestion so that I could upvote anyway.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ "You can get no advantage from prepared statements here" This is wrong, prepared statements remove need for escaping and prevent SQL injection. Your batch script is susceptible to SQL injection.