# Store a SQLite query with parameters in bash variable

Tags: bash, sqlite

I am trying to store a list of rows inside of a variable like in this example:

```
list=$(bash -c 'sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/myplace/mydb.db "SELECT row1 FROM table1"')
```

But when I want to add parameters like in this example:

```
list=$(bash -c 'sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/myplace/mydb.db "SELECT row2 FROM table2 WHERE row2='somevalue'"')
```

It does not work because the command given to bash inside the '' ends after the `WHERE row2=`.

I tried some other variants where I first wrote the results of

```
sqlite3 /home/ubuntu/myplace/mydb.db "SELECT row2 FROM table2 WHERE row2='somevalue'"
```

to some txt, csv or json file just to read it out one line later but that just came out to be not practical.

Is there any other practical possibility?

Comment: Direct parameter substitution is **dangerous**. It's very easy to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks.

Comment: Related: [How to prepare a statement from the CLI interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065990/how-to-prepare-a-statement-from-the-cli-interpreter)